# Starting a process

Tags: c#, automation

As part of SharePoint automation testing, I am trying to open Internet Explorer as another user by using the System.Diagnostics.Process . Here is the following C# code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

// Domain and User Name:
p.StartInfo.Domain = "MYDOMAIN";
p.StartInfo.UserName = "myusername";

// Command to execute and arguments:
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://url/AllItems.aspx";

// Build the SecureString password...
System.String rawPassword = "thepassword";
System.Security.SecureString encPassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (System.Char c in rawPassword)
{
    encPassword.AppendChar(c);
}

p.StartInfo.Password = encPassword;

// The UseShellExecute flag must be turned off in order to supply a password:
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

p.Start();
```

When I run this automated test Visual Studio returns informing me that the test was successful, however Internet Explorer does not open.

Is there something in my code I am missing in order for a window to appear? There is no iexplore process running prior to the test being run.

Answer (score 1):

putting double quotes around the file path (since it contains spaces) may help:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\""
                        ^^                                                        ^^
```

In addition, if your intention is to start this from a service process or dll running in a service such as "SharePoint", then this code will probably not launch the process in the desktop desired. You'll need to set the desktop to `"winsta0\\default"` in the startup info.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestions Gread and Sudhakar. What I am trying to achieve is to open Internet Explorer as another user so I can run some CodedUI to approve a workflow.

Answer (score 1):

To run a process the worker process should have high privileges and this is not an ideal case in any web application. If your purpose is to use IE for unit testing then I would consider using something like [WaitIN](http://watin.org/). If your purpose is for application logic to access a URL and do something then consider using [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx). If you still need a process to be started then create a Windows Service and then expose a web call so in Share Point you can just make a call and your Windows Service can run on local account or some other high privilege account.

Hope this helps and please provide the scenario why you want to start the IE and that can give you a better answer in the forum.